# Datastudio and BigQuery partition column

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have DateTime columns `Order Time` and `Delivery Time` on my BigQuery table. My BQ table has `partition`s on column `Order Time` but in my DataStudio reports I would like to use column `Delivery Time`. `Delivery Time` can be at most 10 days after `Order Time`.

Since querying data is expensive on BigQuery I would like to limit my data by `Partitioned Order Time`.

Is there a way to use only `Delivery Time` and implicitly set `Order Time` on my queries as well? Setting both fields can be time consuming and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a BigQuery partitioned table partitioned by `Order Time`, correct me if I'm wrong. To make sure you can run "`bq ls MY_DATASET`" which will return the field you choose to partition the table.

As you want to limit your query by "order date", I recommend to [filter using the "where"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions) clause:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.name,
  t2.category
FROM
  table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
ON t1.id_field = t2 field2
WHERE
  t1.ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```